# How Can I make my question to reopen?

Tags: discussion, support

I just [issued this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/arm-development-tools?noredirect=1#comment253922_126595), and as I said in there, I really think it can be an enormous help for people just starting with ARM development, specially hobbyist that don't have contact with people from the industry.

I also posted that there is a [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/991/arm-cortex-m3-development-tools?rq=1) which is not closed and I can't see the difference.

Could someone please explain to me how can I change the post so it will be acceptable and what's the difference between mine and the other one so mine has to remain closed and the other is kept open?

Answer (score 5):

You have created a [2010 version](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/991/arm-cortex-m3-development-tools) and a [2014 version](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/arm-development-tools) of essentially the same question about ARM development tools.

- Both version are requests for product recommendations and also opinion polls.  As such, they area off-topic.
- The landscape of the μC development tools is constantly changing.  The information that's useful today might go stale in a year.  (And you know this.  Otherwise, you wouldn't be asking the same question again.)
- The reason why the 2010 didn't get closed is because the standards were more relaxed back then.

Comment: It's not the same question, as I said, he only asks about IDEs and I ask about IDE and Debuggers....IDEs are fine, you can download and test for free....but debuggers you can't, and that's the real issue for me....besides if something changes new answers or updates might follow just as they do in the old questions about "how to solve this problem" when new technologies and therefore answers arrive.